# Weather api for laravel 5.4. Does anyone knows any weather api for laravel 5.4? Give me a suggestion, please

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, weather

**Does anyone knows any weather api for laravel 5.4? Give me a suggestion, please.**

Answer (score 2):

Below are some of weather APIs available for Laravel :

1. [Torann/laravel-weather](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-weather)
2. [gmopx/laravel-owm](https://packagist.org/packages/gmopx/laravel-owm)
3. [nwidart/laravel-forecast](https://packagist.org/packages/nwidart/laravel-forecast)
4. [floodedcodeboy/world-weather-online-laravel](https://www.versioneye.com/php/floodedcodeboy:world-weather-online-laravel/0.10)